# Purpose of /usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm poking around in python3.4 packages and found a file called CDROM.py with a list like:

```
CDROMPAUSE = 0x5301
CDROMRESUME = 0x5302
CDROMPLAYMSF = 0x5303
CDROMPLAYTRKIND = 0x5304
CDROMREADTOCHDR = 0x5305
CDROMREADTOCENTRY = 0x5306
CDROMSTOP = 0x5307
CDROMSTART = 0x5308
CDROMEJECT = 0x5309
CDROMVOLCTRL = 0x530a
```

What do these numbers mean??

Comment: They are [integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) presented in hexadecimal form. If you're asking what the values represent, you're going to need to provide more context.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue28027

Comment: Thanks Josh Lee. Interesting, so I see that that file is no longer needed. My real question is what were those hex numbers indicating? Memory positions? Assembly registers? I'm so intrigued by these mystery numbers for some reason lol. Does anyone have a good explanation?

Answer (score 0):

These are the `ioctl` codes for the Linux CD-ROM interface. The file was generated from `cdrom.h` in the Linux kernel.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h